# Access SQL Subquery in From

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm learning Access and SQL, but I have a problem using subqueries in the from clause I can't seem to figure out.

```
Select *
From (LongSubQuery) as a, (LongSubQuery) as b, (LongSubQuery) as c
Where a.field=b.field=c.field;
```

This works perfectly as long as each of the statements A, B, and C in the from clause returns a record.  If the where clause in any of the three statements prevents the return of a record, then none of the statements will return a result.  I've tried various NZ and is not null statements with no luck.  I'm suspicious it is actually caused by the last line of code making the fields equivalent.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try "left outer join" or "full outer join".

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` is what you want.  There is no `FULL` join in Access SQL.

Comment: Technically I don't think Access has full outer joins.  How would I specify a left outer join in the where clause?

Comment: Assuming you're doing this in an Access session, use the query designer.  Discard that `WHERE` clause.  Then in Design View, drag a line from a field in one table to the matching field in the other table.  Right-click the join line to choose the type of join you want: `INNER`; `LEFT`; or `RIGHT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when you do something like `select * from A, B, C` (where `A, B, C` are data sets), you are returning the cartesian product of `A, B, C`; in other words, you will have `#(A)*#(B)*#(C)` rows (where `#(A)` is the number of rows in set A). So, of course, if one of the sets is empty, the whole set is empty.

**Possible solution:** Use unilateral joins:

```
select *
from 
    (select ...) as a
    left join (select ...) as b on a.aField = b.aField ...
    left join (select ...) as c on b.aField = c.aFiedl ...
```

`left join`  returns all the rows on the left side of the relation and all the matching rows of the right side of the relation if it is fulfilled, and `null` values if it is not fulfilled.

Be careful when you make the relations. Be sure you use the fields you need. Notice that in this case you can define the condition you are using in the `where` clause directly in the join construction.

Comment: Since the `FROM` includes more that one join, it will need extra parentheses.  But, since he is doing this from Design View of the query designer, it will take care of that detail for him. +1